# Represent nested list as an array of strings

Tags: javascript

I have a list which could look like this:

```
let list = [
  {
    name: "Level 1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Level 2",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Level 3A",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Level 4A",
                    children: []
                }
            ],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3B",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3C",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

As you can see it consists of elements with 2 properties: `name` and `children`. This is simple list but it can be nested many levels down and each element could have a lot of children.

Based on that `list` i want to create array of arrays of strings e.g.

```
let levels = [
    ["Level 1"],
    ["Level 1", "Level 2"],
    ["Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3A"],
    ["Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3A", "Level 4A"],
    ["Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3B"],
    ["Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3C"],
]
```

So as you can see each 'row' of my `list` has a representation in my `levels` array.

Could you help me write achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function to traverse the tree structure whilst accumulating the path along the way.

```js
function getLevels(list) {
  const levels = [];
  
  const searchForLevels = ({ name, children }, path) => {
    levels.push([...path, name]);
    path.push(name);
    children.forEach(child => searchForLevels(child, path));
    path.pop();
  };
  
  list.forEach(child => searchForLevels(child, []));
  return levels;
} 


let list = [
  {
    name: "Level 1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Level 2",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Level 3A",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Level 4A",
                    children: []
                }
            ],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3B",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3C",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(getLevels(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by writing a recursive function.

Though on SO, usually, people would suggest you try to solve it yourself first. But I myself find that writing recursive functions is not an easy task (in terms of understanding how it works). So I'm happy to give you a hand.

```
const recursion = ({ name, children }, accumulator = []) => {
  if (name) accumulator.push(name);
  res.push(accumulator);
  children.forEach((element) => recursion(element, [...accumulator]));
  // have to store accumulator in new reference,
  // so it would avoid override accumulators of other recursive calls
};
```

```js
let list = [
  {
    name: "Level 1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Level 2",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Level 3A",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Level 4A",
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3B",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3C",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const res = [];

const recursion = ({ name, children }, accumulator = []) => {
  if (name) accumulator.push(name);
  res.push(accumulator);
  children.forEach((element) => recursion(element, [...accumulator]));
};

list.forEach((element) => recursion(element));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by traversing the tree and printing the path taken at each step

```js
let list = [
  {
    name: "Level 1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Level 2",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Level 3A",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Level 4A",
                    children: []
                }
            ],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3B",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3C",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

let root = list[0]
function Traverse (root, path){
  console.log(path + " " + root.name)
  root.children.forEach(child => Traverse (child, path + " " + root.name));
}

Traverse(root, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take `flatMap` with a recursive callback.

```js
const
    getPathes = ({ name, children }) => children.length
        ? children.flatMap(getPathes).map(a => [name, ...a])
        : [[name]],
    list = [{ name: "Level 1", children: [{ name: "Level 2", children: [{ name: "Level 3A", children: [{ name: "Level 4A", children: [] }] }, { name: "Level 3B", children: [] }, { name: "Level 3C", children: [] }] }] }],
    pathes = list.flatMap(getPathes);

console.log(pathes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```